# Using Google Analytics and Firebase crash report at the same time, how do I keep two copy of GoogleService-Info.plist in an iOS project

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

Dear Fellow Developers

In my iOS project, I have been using Google Analytics. Recently, I am implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging, Analytics, Crash Report. The project has one target, with Debug and Release build configuration. Both Google Analytics and Firebase stuff are in the same target, with the same build configuration. Example, For Debugging, The project is using both Google Analytics and Firebase.

Initially the problem was, Google Analytics and Firebase both use GoogleService-Info.plist for configuration. I couldn't keep two GoogleService-Info.plist. So I renamed the Firebase's plist to Firebase-Info.plist, and init it this way

> ```
> NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Firebase-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
> FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
> [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
> ```

So Google Analytics is using GoogleService-Info.plist and Firebase is using Firebase-Info.plist. The project works without any issue.

The problem comes when I was implementing Firebase Crash Report, it requires a run script like this

> "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${PROJECT_DIR}"/ServiceAccount.json

upload-sym will actually look for GoogleService-Info.plist instead of Firebase-Info.plist. It creates problem because GoogleService-Info.plist is not for Firebase and it has different GOOGLE_APP_ID, it doesn't have PROJECT_ID and API_KEY for the Firebase project. I couldn't make upload-sym to look for Firebase-Info.plist instead of GoogleService-Info.plist.

Is there any open to solve this issue? Thanks a lot in advance, any help is appreciated.

Joe

Comment: Hey did you ever get an answer for this ? How did you finally do it ?